# Excel data validation: Change fill color without changing text

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I have a floor plan with about 50 resources that either need to be marked available, reserved, or occupied.  I chose to use data validation in-cell drop-down list for each resource.  Is it possible to keep the text in the data validation cell, use the source as the drop-down options, and change the fill color based on the selection?  That might be hard to understand so I'll provide an example.

**Example given:**

A1:A3 is the source with Available, Reserved, and Occupied.

Cell D3: Available, Reserved, and Occupied as drop-down list, the fill color will change to green, orange, or red respectively, and it will keep the text in the cell.

Comment: ”FormatCondition” may satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

First place the ComboBox control and set the `.visible` property to `false`. using `.AddItem` method add `Available` and others. to its list. I think you want something like below.

```
Private mrngMyRange As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then 'This restricts the sensitive range to column `D`
        ComboBox1.Visible = True
        ComboBox1.Left = Target.Left
        ComboBox1.Top = Target.Top
        Set mrngMyRange = Target
        ComboBox1.Select
    Else
        ComboBox1.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    'mrngMyRange.Value = ComboBox1.Text

    If ComboBox1.Text = "Available" Then
        mrngMyRange.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Reserved" Then
        mrngMyRange.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Occupied" Then
        mrngMyRange.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

    ComboBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use Data Validation to create the list in based on the values in cells A1:A3 (Available, Reserved, and Occupied) in cell D3.

Then, use Conditional Formatting to setup three rules through "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". You'll need one for each colour, ie.

```
=$D$3="Available" - Applies to: =$D$3 - Format: Green fill
=$D$3="Reserved" - Applies to: =$D$3 - Format: Orange fill
=$D$3="Occupied" - Applies to: =$D$3 - Format: Red fill
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Conditional Formatting** to achieve the same. Example given below is using **MS-Excel 2007**.

Assuming that you have a dropdown already present at D3 (or multiple cells), select the cell (or cells) in which the formatting is required.

In **Home** tab -> go to **Conditional Formatting** option -> select **Highlight Cell Rules** -> **Equal To** option. A dialog box will open as shown in the image below. Enter the cell reference that you want and the format required (e.g. $A$1 for `Available`) and click **OK**.

[image]

Repeat the same for `Reserved` and `Occupied` as well with appropriate formatting.

Comment: That's what I currently have right now, unfortunately it changes the text to the source text.

Comment: Which verion of MS-Excel are you using?

Comment: Our client is using Office 2010.

Comment: Unfortunately Excel 2010 is not installed on my system. But even Excel 2010 forums and guides have mentioned similar methods to achieve this. Are you sure you don't have any other conditional formatting which is overlapping this one?