# EXCEL VBA: Data Validation's background color coding programmatically in a drop-down list and inserting in a Cell

Tags: excel, vba, validation, colors, combobox

A code sample below makes perfectly nice drop-down list in a certain row and column, but I need to insert also color backgrounds programmatically inside cells.

This defines values and colors.

> ```
> optionList(0) = "Not started" --> RED
> optionList(1) = "Planned" --> YELLOW
> optionList(2) = "Started"  --> YELLOW
> optionList(3) = "Failed" --> RED
> optionList(4) = "Passed / Done" --> GREEN
> optionList(5) = "Not applicable" --> GREY
> ```

--> Code below works, but I need instructions how to add colors.

```
Public Function addDataValidation(row As Long, column As Long)

Dim optionList(5) As String

optionList(0) = "Not started"
optionList(1) = "Planned"
optionList(2) = "Started"
optionList(3) = "Failed"
optionList(4) = "Passed / Done"
optionList(5) = "Not applicable"

    With mySheet.Cells(row, column).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(optionList, ",")
    End With

End Function
```

My tested and final solution for this challenge is following like

```
    Public Function addDataValidation(row As Long, column As Long)

Dim optionList(5) As String

optionList(0) = "Not started"
optionList(1) = "Planned"
optionList(2) = "Started"
optionList(3) = "Failed"
optionList(4) = "Passed / Done"
optionList(5) = "Not applicable"

    With mySheet.Cells(row, column).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(optionList, ",")
    End With

    With mySheet.Cells(row, column).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""Not started""")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.colorIndex = 3
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With mySheet.Cells(row, column).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""Planned""")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.colorIndex = 6
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With mySheet.Cells(row, column).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""Started""")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.colorIndex = 6
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With mySheet.Cells(row, column).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""Failed""")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.colorIndex = 3
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With mySheet.Cells(row, column).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""Passed / Done""")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.colorIndex = 4
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

    With mySheet.Cells(row, column).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=""Not applicable""")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.colorIndex = 15
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465932/excel-data-validation-change-fill-color-without-changing-text) helps.

Comment: I don't want to use ComboBox and I would prefer that solution is off-line, without pressing any update buttons which goes through some range.

Comment: Use conditional formatting as suggested.

Comment: please share an example

Comment: Its there in the link in my comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29467110/6075259

Comment: I want to solve the challenge programmatically, that I do something inside my Function addDataValidation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152593/discussion-between-aratiod-and-mrig).